# Connect with R/RStudio to an Oracle DB using Wallet

Tags: r, oracle, unix, wallet

H, I'm quite a newbie on this.

I have a Unix machine with R/RStudio and Python installed.
I need to connect to an Oracle DB in a secure way.
I have created a wallet with mkstore given by Oracle and with Python and cx_Oracle library I have no problems in connecting to this DB, but how can I afford the same result with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the [ROracle doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/ROracle.pdf):

```
## Create connection authenticated with external credentials.
con <- dbConnect(drv, username ="", password="", external_credentials = TRUE)
```

You'll probably need to pass `dbname` too.

Comment: yeah thanks i discover it myself, a normal connection string with the dbName of the Wallet connection and username and password blanked